# Передать данные из UserControl в форму

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Есть главная форма, при нажатии на кнопку происходит открытие формы, в дочерней форме подгружается контрол. Вопрос заключается в следующем: Как передать из контрола в форму данные, закрыть ее, но при при закрытие формы выставить DialogResult.Ok и передать данные в родительскую форму, точнее вывести переданный текст в label и записать данные в переменную.

P.S. Кнопка закрытия формы находится в подключенном контроле.

В главной форме "Родительской форме" есть кнопка с помощью которой происходит открытие дочерней формы

```
private void btn_sel_driver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
get_driver gd = new get_driver(getIDkontr(id));
gd.ShowDialog();
  if (gd.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    btn_sel_driver.Text = //Сюда должен вставится полученный текст из контрола
  }
}
```

На дочерней форме есть элемент 'panel' в него загружается userControl

```
list_driver ld = new list_driver(pid);
content.Controls.Clear();
content.Controls.Add(ld);
```

В userControl находится кнопка с помощью которой должно произойти закрытие дочерней формы и передача данных в родительскую форму

```
private void btn_sel_driver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
get_driver gd = new get_driver(pid);
gd.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
gd.Close();
}
```

Comment: Как понять подгружается ? Покажите Ваш код, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Вставил исходный код. Как передать данные между я знаю, но как передать данные из контрола в дочернею форму потом в родительскую

Answer (score 2):

Ну вам скорее всего придется добавить в родительскую форму свойства, которые вы хотите передать из UserControl'а.

В UserControl'е в конструкторе или каком-нибудь инициализирующем методе передавать ссылку на родительскую форму и перед закрытием записывать необходимые значения. В частном случае это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class A
{
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }

   public void Create()
   {
       var b = new B();
       b.Show(this);
       b.Close(); // После закрытия, в MyProperty будет значение Some Value
   }
}

class B
{
    private A a;

    public void Show(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        a.MyProperty = "Some Value";
    }
}
```

Это должно решить вашу проблему

Answer (score 0):

С закрытием формы решил вопрос вот таким образом.

```
driver_fio = string.Join(",", id);

Controls.Owner.FindForm().Close();
Controls.Owner.FindForm().DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Теперь как передать знание переменной driver_fio обратно в форму родителя?
При закрытии формы ей присваивается значение null

Comment: Ну если вы решили так сделать, то перед закрытием Controls.Owner.FindForm().MyPublicProperty = driver_fio